# CSS @import rule symfony

Tags: php, css, symfony

I want to seperate CSS into smaller parts - create multiple CSS files and use @import to import these files into main style.css file.

File structure:

```
css
|
|-style.css
|
|-folder_1
  |    
  |--custom_1.css    
  |--custom_2.css
```

Problem which I am facing - `@import url('/folder_1/custom_1.css');` is not working and I have out of ideas how to get this to work.

Project I am working with is using Symfony framework.

What I am doing wrong? Also - is there a way how to view full url which this `@import` function is trying to get?

Comment: folder_1 is the root, there are no parent directories?

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP or Symfony. To see what file is being imported with `@import` simply look into network tab in Firebug (or any other developer tools depending on your browser).